# How to get related instruction code from instruction bytes?

Tags: go, x86-64, disassembly

I got the following error message when I run a Go program which contains some Go assembler codes:

```
SIGILL: illegal instruction
PC=0x508c04 m=0 sigcode=2
instruction bytes: 0xc4 0x42 0x68 0xf2 0xea 0xc5 0xf9 0xef 0xc1 0x41 0x9 0xfd 0x45 0x1 0xee 0xc1
```

How can i get related instruction code from the instruction bytes? I tried https://github.com/golang/arch Decode method, but I just got opcode 0.

From the first byte 0xc4, it should be VEX Prefix.

**CPU**: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620)
**Operating system**: Linux

Comment: Use a disassembler. It's `andn r13d,edx,r10d`. It's from BMI1, which your cpu doesn't seem to support.

Comment: https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm is a handy disassembler where you can paste those hex bytes (without the `0x`, and padded to 2 hex digits each: like `c4 42 68 f2 ea c5 f9 ef c1 41 09 fd 45 01 ee c1`) and click "disassemble" as x64.  You're correct, BMI1 `andn` uses a VEX encoding.

Comment: Thx all! This is really a handy tool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ANDN, which is part of the [BMI1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_Bit_manipulation_instruction_set#BMI1_(Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_1)) instruction set. On Intel, BMI1 is supported by Haswell and newer, but your chip is Sandy Bridge, which is a generation (or two, depending on how you count) too old.